# c++ Qt Qwt build issue

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I a Qt neophyte so I apologize in advance if this question is obvious...

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of Qt Creator 5 as well as Qwt (Qt Widgets for Technical Applications) on my Windows7 machine.

Qwt.pro does not build using QT Creator on my windows machine.

It all worked fine on my Ubuntu machine using Qt Creator 4.

Is there a compatibility issue with Qwt and the newest version of Qt??

Comment: Do you mean, you can't get `qmake` to produce a makefile?.. To elaborate: what do you get when you run `qmake` on `Qwt.pro`?

Comment: Make sure `mingw32-make` and `qmake` is added to your PATH. Tell me what do you get when you run `qmake`. For plotting, you can use [this](http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/)

Comment: I don't think that Qwt has an official Qt5 compatible release yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the MinGW version Qt? If not make sure you have installed Visual Studio, which contains the MSVC compiler. To get started use the MinGW version, the MSVC compiler is faster on Windows but more complicated to set up. For testing run qmake in your Qwt directory directly from the Qt console (start menu). Also make sure you can build a simple hello world project with Qt Creator first.